# Printing a function returns an unexpected value, why?

Tags: c++, function

I am passing a value into a function to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, but the console prints an error code which brings up nothing when I Google it.

```
// Function Declarations
float fToC(float degreesF = 32.0);

int main() {
    float fahrenheit = 10; 
    float centigrade = 10;

    centigrade = fToC(fahrenheit); 
    cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC << "C" << endl;

    return 0;
}


// Function Defintions 
float fToC(float degreesF) {
    float degreesC = ((5.0 / 9.0)*(degreesF - 32));
    return degreesC;
}
```

This prints into the console:

```
Freezing Point: 00A31627C
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you are printing out the function and not *centigrade*.

`cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC << "C" << endl;` in the console it is showing the memory address of the function.

You should do something like:

`cout << "Freezing Point: " << centigrade << "C" << endl;`

Answer (score 8):

> but the console prints an error code which brings up nothing when I Google it.

That's not an error code.

You're missing the parenthesis to call a function:

```
 cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC(farenheit) << "C" << endl;
                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the function address is printed instead.

---

You probably meant to print

```
 cout << "Freezing Point: " << centigrade << "C" << endl;
```

as you already calculated the value by calling the function.

Answer (score 7):

Well,

```
cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC << "C" << endl;
```

Pop quiz for you: what is "fToC"?. Why, it's your function, and what you see, as the result, is the meaningless internal memory address where your function's code lives.

You probably meant to write:

```
cout << "Freezing Point: " << centigrade << "C" << endl;
```

Unfortunately, a computer does only what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do.

Answer (score 7):

This is wrong:

```
cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC << "C" << endl;
```

You pass fToC to the console, and so it prints the address of the function. Remove fToC and write centigrade.

Answer (score 6):

```
cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC << "C" << endl;
```

is not correct. You cannot output a function **name** in a `cout` like this and hope it will give you the result you want. It will instead print out the address the function is stored at. You can however **call** the function as

```
cout << "Freezing Point: " << fToC(fahrenheit) << "C" << endl;
```

because fToC(fahrenheit) is actually a `float`, with the parameter you gave to it, so you should get the answer you want instead of the function address. You could also just use:

```
cout << "Freezing Point: " << centigrade << "C" << endl;
```

which you have defined in the previous line.

Comment: _"You cannot output a function name in a cout like this."_ Well, you can. As you see it print's the functions address.

Comment: Yes, poorly worded